# In SQL is there a way to simulate SAS MERGE operation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Lets say I have the following 2 datasets:

```
A           B           C
----------- ----------- -----------
1           100         1000
1           120         1001
2           140         1002
2           160         1003
3           180         1004
3           190         1005
3           200         1006
```

and

```
A           D           E
----------- ----------- -----------
1           61          2000
1           62          2001
1           63          2001
2           64          2002
3           65          2004
3           66          2005
3           67          2006
3           68          2006
```

Is it possible to generate the following output dataset (. represents null)?

```
A           B           C           D           E
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           100         1000        61          2000
1           120         1001        62          2001
1           .           .           63          2001
2           140         1002        64          2002
2           160         1003        .           .
3           180         1004        65          2004
3           190         1005        66          2005
3           200         1006        67          2006
3           .           .           68          2006
```

The merge takes all the records from both tables, and adds them to the result set at most once.

If records join they are not multiplied as in a classical sql join. Each record is aligned with a matching record and when they run out of records null is inserted.

I've been thinking that perhaps the new partitioning functions can achieve this, but I've been away from SQL too long now and I cant think of a way to do this "special join".

I've also considered making a distinct list of the keys and then left joining them to the 2 tables, but then I get stuck, because the join will still multiply the record counts..

Comment: have you tried `full outer join` ?

Comment: yes, but that wont work because it multiplies the matching records

Comment: look at A=1 - i'll get 2x3=6 records instead of Max(2,3) = 3

Comment: also full outer join won't give me nulls instead of duplicating a record

Comment: You can do this by using `ROWNUMBER()` to assign an additional arbitrary key to each dataset, then use `UNION ALL` to combine them. I'm sure someone else will take the time to explain in detail

Comment: so something like add a "row number" to each joining-key repeat, and join based on that key and the row number?

Comment: So in SAS you are merging `by a;`. Right?

Comment: yes - merging by a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `row_number()` windowing function. Naming the two datasets `DS1` and `DS2` the result will look like this:

```
WITH DS1Seq As (
    SELECT A, B, C, row_number() OVER (partition by A order by A, B, C) As SeqNumber 
    FROM DS1
),
DS2Seq As (
    SELECT A, D, E, row_number() OVER (partition by A order by A, D, E) As SeqNumber
    FROM DS2
)
SELECT coalesce(DS1Seq.A, DS2Seq.A) As A, B, C, D, E
FROM DS1Seq
FULL JOIN DS2Seq on DS1Seq.A = DS2Seq.A AND DS1Seq.SeqNumber = DS2Seq.SeqNumber
```

Comment: small typo, second with clause should probably reference DS2